# Scrolling with $.scrollTop(0) desn't work correctly on iPhone Safari. Sometimes

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, safari, responsive-design

I've got a responsive website and have problemes on iOs Safari Browser with scrolling to top of the page after switching the page by ajax.

**Sometimes it works, sometimes not.**

I use the following function to scroll to top:

```
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('.mydiv').scrollTop(0);
    },1)
```

Maybe this part has something to do with my broblem. I hide the adressbar on iOs devices.

```
    function hideAddressBar() {
        if( navigator.userAgent.match( /(iphone|ipod)/i ) ) {

            document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'scroll';
            document.body.style.height = '120%';
            $(".mydiv").height('120%');

        }
    }
```

It works perfect on Desktop Browsers.

$(window).scrollTop(0) is no option.

Comment: probably you should use $(window).scrollTop(0) ?

Comment: I can't share a link, because it's for a customer and not public yet. $(window).scrollTop(0) is no option. I tried this. I scroll in mydiv.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollIntoView();
```